# How to get the nearest subdirectory of a file as output in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, directory, devops

I need to get only the nearest subdirectory and file name from the file path as follows.

Ex:-

```
(1)E:\Dump\DumpText-1.txt - Dump\DumpText-1.txt

(2)E:\Dump\SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt - SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt

(3)E:\Dump\SubDump3\Sub_SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt -Sub_SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt
```

My PowerShell Script as follows:

```html
Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process {if (!$_.PSIsContainer) {$_.FullName; $_.FullName -replace "^.*?\\"; " "}}
```

Comment: on a file object, you have a property named >>> `.Directory.Parent` <<< that will give you the parent dir of the current dir. a similar property exists on directory objects >>> `.Parent` <<< ///// that can chain all the way up your dir tree ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Directory property of the object:

```
Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.FullName) - $($_.Directory.Name)\$($_.Name)"
}
```

just use the name of the Directory object and then the name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in my eyes is to split the string at the backslashes:

```
$splitString = "E:\Dump\SubDump3\Sub_SubDump1\DumpText-1.txt" -split "\\"
```

(since the backslash is the escape character, it has to be escaped by a second backslash).

`$splitString` now is an array of all the parts between the backslashes. Now you can access the last and the second-last part of this array by `$splitString[-1]` (the filename) and `$splitString[-2]` (the name of the direct parent folder).